# Lifting small objects at very low speed

Tags: motor

I'm working on project where I have to lift up/down an object about 5-7 kg heavy at speed of about 6.6 mm per second. Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

I was looking at asynchronous motor and reductors for them but reductors at very small speed are very expensive (1000 euros). Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: Fine pitch lead screw, maybe driving a scissor jack

Comment: thanks for reply, but it has to hang on cable.

Comment: Weld the cable to the top of the scissor jack?? Is there anything else that would be convenient to know before we brainstorm?

Comment: How far does it have to lift? How often does it have to lift? Whats the expected service life: Days, Weeks, or Years? Isn't this more of a mechanical problem than electronics?

Comment: it will work for about 6 hours a day for 2 weeks, in 5 minutes it has to lift object for 2 meters, then stop, wait few minutes then go down for 5 and everything again. It is mechanical and electrical problem, i know :)

Comment: Definitely a job for a gearbox. I'd start by looking in automotive and marine equipment catalogs for small electric winches, which seem to be available starting in the £100 range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's look at the power requirement.  7 kg on earth weighs about 70 N.  That times 6.6 mm/s is only half a Watt.  There will be friction and other effects to make things harder at the motor, so I'd get about a 2 W to motor.

You want a travel of 2 m from a cable.  That probably means the cable unwinding and winding onto a drum that is rotated by the motor.  If you can have a second cable on the same drum winding opposite with a 7 kg counterbalance on it, the power requirments and wear on parts of the system will go down dramatically.

You will need gearing no matter what, so start by looking for a suitable motor and add gearing to reduce its speed.  A lot of motors are available with "gear heads" already built on.  You have some flexibility on the diameter of the drum, so should be able to accomodate a wide enough range to find a gearhead motor that does what you want, or find or make a reduction gear train to add to a bare motor.

Comment: thank you very much, counter balance is quite good idea :) do you maybe think that releys and different resistor before DC motor would do the trick? there is also a problem that there is heater on object so there will be metal cable (i don't know precise word in english for that) and also that it need to stand for few minutes at lowest position. so, it's always in the air and it needs braking system.

Comment: @jippie: Good catch, typo fixed.

Comment: @Zlis: Relays and such before the motor aren't going to help in converting the native high speed and low torque of the motor to the low speed and high torque you need.  If the load has to remain stationary, a worm gear drive might help.  The right counterweight will also help a lot.

Comment: ok, i have one more question, do you have any idea how to put counterweight on the otherside of cable drum? beacause i think at some point help from ballast will be non linear and there will have to be much more control when lifting  from motor, if you get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a DC motor with a gearbox attached to it. You can calculate the torque needed and then look for a motor that suites your need.

You can take a look at the following page for torque calculation:

[All about torque](http://www.solarbotics.net/bftgu/tutorials_mech_torque.html)

Or if you are planning to use a screw (I know you said a rope, but just in case you want to see other option including more mathematical calculation for it) then look at this page:

[Leadscrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leadscrew#Mechanics)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a system of pulleys might do the trick. It would provide the mechanical advantage and the speed reduction you seek plus it would use a rope.